# MySQL - Create table with current date and return date that adjusts

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table in MySQL(current version) that fills in the current date and the return date 7 days later.

I have the code set up like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Loans (
loan_id int(5) not null auto_increment primary key,
loan_date CURDATE,
return_date CURDATE (getdate()+7),
loan_notes varchar(200)
);
```

Obviously, this is not working. I have tried it with DATE, DATETIME (basically any variation on DATE) and the MySQL helpguide is... not so helpful here.
I tried checking a few other answers on here but haven't had any luck.
I could set a form linked to MySQL that asks for the user to input the info, but I would rather have it auto-generate if I can.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE Loans (loan_id int(5) not null auto_increment primary key, createdAt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, loan_date DATE AS (DATE(createdAt)), return_date DATE AS (DATE(createdAt) + INTERVAL 7 DAY), loan_notes varchar(200) );`

Comment: Thank you for the help! My first database with MySQL...